# How to add sticky footer in admin template 5.3.0

Tags: bootstrap-5, sticky-footer

I would like to add sticky footer to admin template 5.3.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/dashboard/). I tried with my level best. i am not succeeded. Need you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code *after* `.container-fluid` in your example dashboard HTML:

```
<footer class="fixed-bottom p-3 bg-dark-subtle">
    <span class="text-muted">Place fixed footer content here.</span>
</footer>
```

The class `.fixed-bottom` makes the `footer` stick to the bottom of the page. You can change the classes `p-3` (gives the footer padding) and `bg-dark-subtle` (gives the footer a background color) to your liking. You can change the content inside the `footer` too.

So given that example dashboard the final layout order should be:

```
<body>
<header>...</header>
<div class="container-fluid">...</div>
<footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

Good luck.

Comment: thanx. works great. but i need something like this see the link pls. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/. same footer in admin  template. "body h-100".